# Datagram socket isn't receiving

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I have a server-client basis going on here but it seems that when the server and client handshake I can get the server to send a message back to the client.

This is the server side

```
    package me.game.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.game.WorldOfTrade;

public class NetServerHandler implements Runnable {

    public static final int max_packet_size = 512;
    public static final int max_clients = 5;

    DatagramSocket socket;

    List<DatagramSocket> connectedClients;

    public NetServerHandler(short port) {
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            connectedClients = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to initialize the server...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean handlePacket(byte[] pck, InetAddress add) throws IOException{
        String str = new String(pck);
        str = str.trim();
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("ping")){
            System.out.println("Client ==>> Us: ping");
            sendPacket(easyPacket("pong").getData(), add);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public DatagramPacket easyPacket(String buffer){
        byte[] buff = buffer.getBytes();
        return new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running server!");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(WorldOfTrade.isRunning){
                DatagramPacket pck = new DatagramPacket(new byte[max_packet_size], max_packet_size);

                try {
                    socket.setSoTimeout(200);
                    socket.receive(pck);
                    DatagramSocket newSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                    newSocket.connect(pck.getAddress(), 25565);
                    if(connectedClients.size() > 0){
                        continue;
                    }

                    connectedClients.add(newSocket);
                    System.out.println("Found new client! "+new String(pck.getData()));
                    sendPacket(easyPacket("pong").getData(), pck.getAddress());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if(!(e instanceof SocketTimeoutException)){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            }
            }
        ).start();
        while (WorldOfTrade.isRunning) {
            if(connectedClients.isEmpty()){
                continue;
            }
                int i = 0;
                    //System.out.println("Checking "+i);
                    DatagramSocket sck = socket;
                    DatagramPacket pck = new DatagramPacket(new byte[max_packet_size], max_packet_size);
                    try {
                        sck.setSoTimeout(0);
                        sck.receive(pck);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if(e instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
                        }else{
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        if(!handlePacket(pck.getData(), pck.getAddress())){
                            //sendPacket(easyPacket("pong").getData(), i);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }



        socket.close();
    }

    public void sendPacket(byte[] buffer, InetAddress add) throws IOException {
        if(buffer.length > max_packet_size){
            System.out.println("Couldnt send packet because it was to big!");
            return;
        }
        DatagramPacket pck = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, add, 25565);
        System.out.println("Sending packet to "+add.getHostAddress()+":"+25565);
        socket.connect(add, 25565);
        socket.send(pck);

    }

}
```

This is the client side

```
package me.game.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import me.game.WorldOfTrade;

public class NetHandler implements Runnable {

    DatagramSocket sck;

    public NetHandler(String connect){
        try {
            sck = new DatagramSocket();
            sck.connect(InetAddress.getByName(connect), (short)25565);
            sck.setSoTimeout(0);
        } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean handlePacket(byte[] pck) throws IOException{
        String str = new String(pck);
        str = str.trim();
        System.out.println("Recieved Packet: "+str);
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("pong")){
            System.out.println("Server ==>> Us : pong");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("!");
        return false;
    }

    public DatagramPacket easyPacket(String buffer){
        byte[] buff = buffer.getBytes();
        return new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running client connector!");
        boolean timedOut = false;

        try {
            sendPacket(easyPacket("ping").getData(), sck);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        int update = 0;
        while (WorldOfTrade.isRunning) {
            if(WorldOfTrade.frame == null){
                continue;
            }
            WorldOfTrade.frame.setTitle("Timed Out: "+timedOut);
            update++;
            if (update % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    sendPacket(easyPacket("ping").getData(), sck);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }else{
                DatagramPacket pck = new DatagramPacket(new byte[NetServerHandler.max_packet_size], NetServerHandler.max_packet_size);
                while(true){
                try {
                    //System.out.println("Client:  Listening for packet "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                    sck.setSoTimeout(500);
                    sck.receive(pck);
                    System.out.println(new String(pck.getData()));
                    handlePacket(pck.getData());
                    timedOut = false;
                    break;

                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
//                  if(e instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
//                      timedOut = true;
//                      continue;
//                  }
                    try {
                        sendPacket(easyPacket("ping").getData(), sck);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

            }
        }
        sck.close();
    }

    public void sendPacket(byte[] buffer, DatagramSocket sck) throws IOException {
        if(buffer.length > NetServerHandler.max_packet_size){
            System.out.println("Couldnt send packet because it was to big!");
            return;
        }
        DatagramPacket pck = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, sck.getInetAddress(), 25565);

        sck.send(pck);

    }



}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question what the problem is. Is the server not receiving the datagram from client or are you unable to send a response to it?

Comment: I believe that the client can receive the message.

Comment: You realise you are converting a String to a byte array to a DatagramPacket to yet another byte array to yet another DatagramPacket? And that you are sending to your own InetAddress?  Not the peer's?

Comment: Have a look at the consequences of calling sendPacket(easyPacket(...)...) for a start: then have a look at where you're getting the target address of the sent datagram from. But why you need someone else to explain your own code to you is a mystery.

Comment: Ive redone it but it still does not work. How can I find out where the datagram packet came from?

Comment: It's in the packet. When you reply, use the same packet you received the request from and just change the data.

Comment: Also would I use getAddress() to get the inet address the packet comes from?

Comment: Sure but only if you need it for some other reason. Leaving it where it is is adequate for replying.